# ImportError when installing Colorama

Tags: python, colorama

I installed `Colorama` into Google Colab.
When I tried to import it, it shows `ImportError`:

```
import colorama

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-88ec09736251> in <module>()
----> 1 import colorama
2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/colorama/ansitowin32.py in <module>()
      4 import os
      5 
----> 6 from .ansi import AnsiFore, AnsiBack, AnsiStyle, Style, BEL
      7 from .winterm import WinTerm, WinColor, WinStyle
      8 from .win32 import windll, winapi_test
ImportError: cannot import name 'BEL'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.
To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
```

How can I get rid from this problem?

Comment: Try reinstalling it by typing `!pip install colorama` in collab cell and then running it by pressing `shift+enter` or by clicking on run button.

Answer (score 0):

Do..
**`pip install colorama`**
and its work.